# nagios: alternatives to SMART disk checking?

Tags: nagios, smart

I'm attempting to repurpose some older Dell PE 29xx machines. These have PERC RAID controllers so the SMART testing isn't working. Is there an SNMP alternative or do I need to start slogging through OpenManage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have OpenManage installed (Dell has instructions for using their [OpenManage software repositories](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/OMSA)), you can use [`check_openmanage`](http://folk.uio.no/trondham/software/check_openmanage.html) via NRPE.  `check_openmanage` will report on the status of the disks behind the RAID controllers among its other tests.

Answer (score 3):

There are [RAID-controller specific plugins](http://exchange.nagios.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=search&Itemid=74&searchword=megaraid) that work fine with the PERC controllers, since they're just megaraid devices in disguise.

Depending on what you want to monitor exactly, [check_megaraid_sas](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Storage-Systems/RAID-Controllers/check_megaraid_sas/details) might work for you. I use it with a number of megaraid-based controllers, including some PERC5s.

There are also plugins that are just a wrapper around smartctl (like [check_smartctl](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_smartctl/details), [check_smartmon](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_smartmon/details), etc.), which is able to get some data through megaraid controllers. See the [smartctl manpage](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/man/smartctl.8.html) for details. To see if these will work for you, try something like this:

```
smartctl -a -d megaraid,0 /dev/sda
```

[Many people have rewritten/modified](http://exchange.nagios.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=search&Itemid=74&searchword=check_smart) these smartctl-based plugins. You may be able to use one as-is or adapt to your specific needs.